# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when splitting a string read from a file

Tags: java, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I am reading a file one line at a time. Each line in the file contains two numbers separated by a space. To work with both the numbers I used the split function and created an array to store the values. However, when I run my program it gives the arrayIndexOutofBoundsException. I have used the split function before. I can't seem to figure out why its displaying it now.
Each line in my text file looks like this:

5 15

3 7

code:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("measurements.rtf"));
String line = null;


  line= reader.readLine(); 

  String[] dimensions = line.split("\\s");   \\ splitting the line into an array
  String widthS = dimensions[0];
  String heightS = dimensions[1];
  System.out.println(widthS);

  width = Integer.valueOf(widthS);
  height = Integer.valueOf(heightS);

  System.out.println(height + width);     

}

  catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  System.out.println("Error! D:\nFile not found.");
  System.out.println(e);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println("Error");   // array out of bounds exception
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

My text file:
10 5

1000 1001

21 13

9999 888

345 1277

Comment: Seems to me that you're not actually splitting the line. Perhaps print the resulting array each time and see what's going on?

Comment: simply check the length of array before using it.

Comment: @user3580294 post all your textfiles contents

Comment: Are you splitting an empty line? You should verify the `dimensions` length before using.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Wrong one :P

Comment: Your code looks like you are reading the same file 5 times and I think what you want is to read the first 5 text lines in the file. If that's the case, you should correct the for clause. Also, you should free the BufferedReader after you are done with it.

Comment: Yes i need to read the text lines individually. They are five in total. I will fix that

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your code so you can really loop over all the file lines. Second check the length of the array. Third, print the line currently being read so you can se if the problem is with the file content.

Ex:

```
String fileName = "measurements.rtf";

BufferedReader reader;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    String line = null;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Line: " + line);
        String dimensions[] = line.split("\\s");
        if(dimensions.length == 2) {
            int width = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[0]);
            int height = Integer.parseInt(dimensions[1]);

            //...
        } else {
            //wrong content in line!
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle FileNotFoundException
} catch(IOException e) {
    // Handle IOException
} catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    //Handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your input file has empty line at the end of the file hence when "splitted"

String[] dimensions of size 1 and you get arrayIndexOutofBoundsException in the line

String heightS = dimensions[1];

Comment: It shows the same error five times for every line I read not only the last one.

Comment: It shows error for the first string... You read five time first string from the file (because you create FileReader in the cycle body)